# Calculating repetitive permutations of an array

Tags: c, algorithm

Let's say I have an array with 5 elements. How can I calculate all possible repetitive permutations of this array in C.

Edit: What I mean is creating all possible arrays by using that 5 number. So the positon matters.

Example:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

[1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,2]
[1,1,1,2,3]
.
.
```

Comment: [1,1,1,1,1] is not a permutation of [1,2,3,4,5]. [3,2,5,4,1] is

Comment: @BlackBear there is a term `permutation with repetition` and `[1,1,1,1,1]` is a valid permutation with repetition of [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: You seem to be talking about [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations) rather than [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), although I suppose it's a form of permutation if you're concerned with the order as well as the elements.

Comment: Is there an accepted term for what OP is looking for? Something like "all possible arrays of size 5 with elements from [1,2,3,4,5]," but shorter?

Comment: @Caleb I think here permutation is different from combination in the sense that `[1,2,1,2,1]` is different from `[1,1,1,2,2]`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Yes, that's a varation with repetition, and [here's some Java code for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366074/code-for-variations-with-repetition-combinatorics)

Comment: I'm not sure about the terms but you can easily understand what I mean in the example.

Comment: Off the top of my head I can only come up with five nested loops (as far as being the most straightforward). Is there a better way?

Comment: @izomorphius I agree (modified my comment to include that possibility), but it wasn't clear what the OP was looking for before his/her edit.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: if `array` contains no duplicates then the accepted term I'd use is that we want all length-5 *strings* of symbols from the *alphabet* in `array`. If `array` does contain duplicates then I'm not sure what output the questioner wants, but if the output should contain dupes when the input does, then "all strings" doesn't describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int increment(size_t *dst, size_t len, size_t base) {
    if (len == 0) return 0;
    if (dst[len-1] != base-1) {
        ++dst[len-1];
        return 1;
    } else {
        dst[len-1] = 0;
        return increment(dst, len-1, base);
    }
}
```

Armed with this function you can iterate over all repetitive permutations of (0 ... 4) starting from `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. The function will return 0 when it runs out of repetitive permutations.

Then for each repetitive permutation in turn, use the contents as indexes into your array so as to get a repetitive permutation of the array rather than of (0 ... 4).

Answer (score 4):

A common way to generate combinations or permutations is to use recursion: enumerate each of the possibilities for the first element, and prepend those to each of the combinations or permutations for the same set reduced by one element. So, if we say that you're looking for the number of permutations of *n* things taken *k* at a time and we use the notation perms(*n*, *k*), you get:

```
perms(5,5) = {
    [1, perms(5,4)]
    [2, perms(5,4)]
    [3, perms(5,4)]
    [4, perms(5,4)]
    [5, perms(5,4)]
}
```

Likewise, for perms(5,4) you get:

```
perms(5,4) = {
    [1, perms(5,3)]
    [2, perms(5,3)]
    [3, perms(5,3)]
    [4, perms(5,3)]
    [5, perms(5,3)]
}
```

So part of perms(5,5) looks like:

```
[1, 1, perms(5,3)]
[1, 2, perms(5,3)]
[1, 3, perms(5,3)]
[1, 4, perms(5,3)]
[1, 5, perms(5,3)]
[2, 1, perms(5,3)]
[2, 2, perms(5,3)]
...
```

Defining perms(*n*, *k*) is easy. As for any recursive definition, you need two things: a base case and a recursion step. The base case is where *k* = 0: perms(*n*, 0) is an empty array, []. For the recursive step, you generate elements by prepending each of the possible values in your set to all of the elements of perms(*n*, *k*-1).

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question correctly, you need to generate all 5 digit numbers with digits 1,2,3,4 and 5. So there is a simple solution - generate all numbers base five up to `44444` and then map the 0 to 1, 1 to 2 and so on. Add leading zeros where needed - so `10` becomes `00010` or `[1,1,1,2,1]`.

NOTE: you don't actually **have** to generate the numbers themselves, you may just iterate the numbers up to 5**5(excluding) and for each of them find the corresponing sequence by getting it's digits base 5.

Answer (score 2):

In your given example, each position could be occupied by either `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`. As there are 5 positions, the total number of possibilities = `5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 = 5 ^ 5 = 3125`. In general, it would be `N ^ N`. (where ^ is the exponentiation operator).

To generate these possibilities, in each of the positions, put the numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, one by one, and increment starting from the last position, similar to a 5 digit counter.

Hence, start with `11111`. Increment the last position to get `11112` ... until `11115`. 
Then wrap back to `1`, and increment the next digit `11121` continue with `11122` ... `11125`, etc. Repeat this till you reach the first position, and you would end at `55555`.