# Find all Combinations of Charset

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I'm trying to figure out a way to get all combinations of a string from a charset, at a fixed length.
For example, Charset:

```
{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' }
```

For this example, I'm using a length of 5.

```
aaaaa
abaaa
aabaa
aaaba
aaaab
abbaa
aabba
...
zzzzz
```

I've tried working out a pattern:

```
AAAAA
 +
ABAAA
 -+
AABAA
  -+
AAABA
   -+
AAAAB
 ++ -
ABBAA
 - +
AABBA
  - +
AAABB
 +  -
ABABA
   -+
ABAAB
 -+
AABAB
  -+
AAABB
 ++ -
ABBBA
 -  +
AABBB
 + -
ABABB
  +-
ABBAB
   +
ABBBB
```

But I'm stuck.

This is not a homework assignment.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit:

Here is how I did it. The accepted response below didn't get all the combos, but this does:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 61; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 61; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 61; c++) {
                for (int d = 0; d < 61; d++) {
                    for (int e = 0; e < 61; e++) {
                        System.out.println(charset[a] + "" + charset[b]
                                + charset[c] + charset[d] + charset[e]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did zzzzz end up in your set with the charset you selected?

Comment: My bad, the charset is supposed to be a-z.

Comment: You could use recursion.

Comment: OP clearly fell asleep while listing all possibilities. (@AmirAfghani)

Comment: You realize that for 5 digits, with 26 characters, the number of combinations is almost 12 million (26^5 = 11881376)... you really want to print all that out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for Variations with repetition (combinatorics)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366074/code-for-variations-with-repetition-combinatorics)

Comment: @asaini007 I'm actually doing 0-9, a-z, A-Z, which is about 916 million combinations. I'm over half way done too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library might help you [cppitertools](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools). With this library you can just do it like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};                                              
for (auto i : combinations(v,3)) {                                             
    //std::cout << i << std::endl;                                             
    for (auto j : i ) std::cout << j << " ";                                   
    std::cout<<std::endl;                                                      
}
```

In your question you say combinations, but from the output you give it looks like you want combinations with replacement, so just keep that in mind, they are pretty similar

---

You can also do it with just for loops (this is combinations with replacement).

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j < size; ++j) {
        for (int k = j; k < size; ++k) {
            //print i j k indices
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would give all permutations with repitition, but of size 3; OP wanted size 5 which would require 5 nested for loops.

Comment: @ijkilchenko it's just an example, it's pretty easy to change, also I would recommend just using the link I gave anyway

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there would be a way to dynamically change the number of `for` loops based on the desired size...?

Comment: @asaini007 as I said the link would do that just fine, but I didn't feel like rewriting a function to do so I just wrote the example with for loops

Comment: @ijkilchenko you don't think what?

Comment: @aaronman, Nevermind. I misunderstood what you meant by "dynamically change the number of for loops."

Comment: @ijkilchenko I didn't write that

Comment: This works quite nicely, and is easily expandable. I considered for loops like this, but it was really messing with my head. Thanks!

Comment: Put correct code in the OP, this had a bug.

Comment: @ModifyYou the code you posted does the cartesian product, not combinations

Answer (score 1):

You need to find all combinations of length *k* consisting of characters from the sequence [*c*<sub>0</sub> ... *c*<sub>*n*-1</sub>]. The total number of combinations is *n*<sup>*k*</sup>.

One way is to count from 0 through *n*<sup>*k*</sup>-1, express each value in base *n* with zero padding to the left, and use each digit as an index into the sequence:

```
/**
 * Generate all combinations of length len using the supplied char array
 */
public String[] generateCombos(int k, char[] chars) {
    final int n = chars.length;
    final int nCombos = (int) Math.pow(n, k);
    final String[] result = new String[nCombos];
    final StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    final StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < nCombos; ++i) {
        // generate zero-padded string representation of i base n
        sb1.setLength(0);
        final String indices = Integer.toString(i, n);
        for (int j = k - indices.length(); j > 0; --j) {
            sb1.append('0');
        }
        sb1.append(indices);
        // process each digit
        sb2.setLength(0);
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
            sb2.append(chars[Integer.parseInt(sb1.substring(j, j + 1), n)]);
        }
        result[i] = sb2.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This will work for any result string length and for any number of distinct characters from `Character.MIN_RADIX` to `Character.MAX_RADIX` (2-36 characters).